# Icinga Hosts not showing up... upgrade from 1.4.1 to 1.6.1

Tags: nagios, icinga

Anyone bump into a problem in 1.6.1 where hosts don't show up in the Classic Web GUI.  The number of monitored hosts increases but the only actual host that shows up in host detail is "localhost".

Tried reinstalling from scratch, copying localhost.cfg as a new file, included it in icinga.cfg, reloaded icinga, number of hosts "2 UP" and still only "localhost" is displaying.

I've also checked cgi.cfg, I've tried disabling authorizations but to no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with object.cache.  This file was not being updated on an Icinga reload.  I have to manually delete the file and reload Icinga for it to update with the new hosts.